# MongoDB find() can return distinct records?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it a way to call `MongoDB` `find()` method, and get **distinct** records? Or should I loop the result set?

```
collection.find({
    'recordType' : recordType,
    'date' : {
        $gte : new Date(dateFrom)
    },
    'operation' : 'delete'
}, {
    fields : {
        'date' : 0,
        'operation' : 0
    }
}).toArray(function (err, results) {

    jsonResult.push(results);

    response.write(JSON.stringify(jsonResult));
    response.end()
});
```

Comment: You will get only the records that matches the query you are using to find.

Comment: Do you want to project `date` and `operation` fields by using `{fields : {'date':0, 'operation':0}}` ?

Comment: could you add expected document example?

Comment: Yes, it is a projection in the query. Adjusted question, wants to filter duplicates in resultset.

Comment: Distinct values in which field? see  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: 2 record where each field equal should not possible

Answer (score 1):

"collection.find" doesn't have distinct. You may need to use distinct separately. However, you can include the filter criteria in the below option.

```
distinct(key[, query][, options], callback)
```

Example:

testMethod - distinct values of this field;
build - is the filter criteria

```
collection.distinct('testMethod', {'build':1}, function(err, item) {
      console.log("item:" + JSON.stringify(item));

      db.close();
    });
```